# Which database to use for quickly and pygtk

Tags: software-center, application-development, quickly, pygtk

I'm writing application using **quickly Pygtk** and **glade**.

this application should have database connection (such as **MySQL**) for reading and writing data from the local or outsourcing machine \ server.

However, in my machine there is **MySQL** installed, but when releasing the app it should be installed on another ubuntu machine, which may not have mysql and moreover not the same database with the required database name and structure....

So my questions are:

1. Is it a good choice using mysql as database

   1.2    If not what is?
2. Is it possible to embed mysql or other database program during the installation from ubuntu software center?

   2.2 If it's possible: how (any tutorial?)
3. Where to store secure data outside the mysql (or whatever) for connecting the database every time a user launch the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using an outside MySQL, like xeround

Consider using XML, it can be a poor mans dB.

If you REALLY need mysql.  Then you can make mysql-server a dependency for your app.  But that's not a good idea... It will require you setting up mysql on install of your app.  That can get tricky.

A trick for setting up the database once you install mysql, is to go to phpmyadmin, and "export" your db.  Choose sql export.  Then open the file it downloads.  It will be a massive sql command.  Copy-paste than into your program, and once you get the needed info from the user (mysql username/password), you can execute that export, and then their database will look identical to the one you created on your local machine.

Though again, I typically recommend against using mysql-server on local machines unless its REALLY needed.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using SQLite as database engine. It is very easy to use because it stores everything on disk in a single file, and Python comes with a [SQLite module](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3) by default.

You can also use an ORM, such as [SQLObject](http://www.sqlobject.org/) or [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) so you write your code once, and can deploy on all kind of database engines. It makes things more fun too, because of the Pythonic approach.

Answer (score 0):

@triunenature suggested using an external (hosted) database like Xeround. I should note that this would introduce very high latency, but it could be acceptable if the application does not query the database intensively, or if perhaps you can do things in an asynchronous manner with some sort of local cache to hold the data until needed by the application. Certainly it would get around the pain of embedding the database with the application. Just in case this is a relevant scenario, I wanted to mention that Xeround has shut down, but there are several alternatives, both for [MySQL](http://cleardb.com) (ClearDB) and other popular databases - since you are considering other options - such as [Postgres](https://postgres.heroku.com/) (Heroku Postgres), [Redis](http://redis-cloud.com) (Redis Cloud), and [MongoDB](http://www.mongolab.com) (Mongolab).